# Capybara: How to test the title of a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In a Rails 3 application using Steak, Capybara and RSpec how do I test the page's title?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Since the version **2.1.0** of capybara there are methods on the session to deal with the title.
You have

```
page.title
page.has_title? "my title"
page.has_no_title? "my not found title"
```

So you can test the title like:

```
expect(page).to have_title "my_title"
```

According to [github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863](http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863) the following is also working with capybara **2.0**:

```
expect(first('title').native.text).to eq "my title"
```

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to search for the `title` element to make sure it contains the text you want:

```
page.should have_xpath("//title", :text => "My Title")
```

Comment: I get a Failure/Error: page.should have_xpath("//title", "home")
     wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Comment: And the code is: scenario "The user is logged in and can see his home page" do
    visit('/')
    page.should have_xpath("//title", "home")
  end

Comment: Oops, forgot that the second parameter is supposed to be a hash... Check my revised answer.

Comment: I didn't really want to post this as an answer, though I feel it could be (I know it's not very ruby-ish).  `page.should have_content('<title>Your Title</title>')`

Comment: I should further add that `page.should have_content()` and `page.has_content?()` seem to not work as beautifully as the xpath methods.

Comment: The message when the test fails is really weird.  It'll say e.g. `expected xpath "//title" with text "Notifications" to return something` if the title doesn't match (in this case) `Notifications`.  This is much less helpful than the normal "expected vs got" pattern.

Comment: This code doesn't work anymore with capybara 2: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863

Answer (score 14):

This works under Rails 3.1.10, Capybara 2.0.2 and Rspec 2.12, and allows matching partial contents:

```
find('title').native.text.should have_content("Status of your account::")
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually used this to monkey patch Capybara, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my spec helper:

```
class Capybara::Session
  def must_have_title(title="")
    find('title').native.text.must_have_content(title)
  end
end
```

Then I can just use:

```
it 'should have the right title' do
  page.must_have_title('Expected Title')
end
```

Comment: That's a nice addition to spec helper!

Answer (score 3):

In order to test for the title of a page with Rspec and Capybara 2.1 you could use

1. `expect(page).to have_title 'Title text'`

   another option is
2. `expect(page).to have_css 'title', text: 'Title text', visible: false`
   Since Capybara 2.1 the default is `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true`, and because the title element is invisible you need the option `visible: false` for the search to include non visible page elements.

Answer (score 2):

Testing the Title of each page can be done in a much easier way with RSpec.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    before(:each) do
      get 'home'
      @base_title = "Ruby on Rails"
    end

    it "should have the correct title " do
      response.should have_selector("title",
                                :content => @base_title + " | Home")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is easier than page.should have_xpath("//title", :text => "My Title")?

Comment: Rendering views in controller tests is not my cup of tea. I vote for using of integration tests (and capybara) for pate title verification.

Comment: capybara 2, only accepts :text not :content as parameter. The content of a title tag cannot be checked with the latest capybara: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `subject` to `page` and then write an expectation for the page's `title` method:

```
subject{ page }
its(:title){ should eq 'welcome to my website!' }
```

In context:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'static welcome pages' do
  subject { page }

  describe 'visit /welcome' do
    before { visit '/welcome' } 

    its(:title){ should eq 'welcome to my website!'}
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

`it { should have_selector "title", text: full_title("Your title here") }`