# Capybara: How to test a stylesheet of a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I want to have the ability to *test* the correct [swapping of a stylesheet](https://github.com/ramontayag/jquery-styler) in my test suite. With this post about [testing the page title using Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5129423/61018), I thought I would be able to test any `link` tags in the `head` section of the page. But it seems I am mistaken.

With a step like this:

```
save_and_open_page
page.should have_xpath("//link") # just something as simple as this, first.
```

`save_and_open_page` generates a HTML like this (with some stuff removed for brevity):

```
<head>
  ...
  <link href="/home/ramon/source/unstilted/public/system_test/stylesheets/fancake/css/2.css?1323572998" type="text/css" class="jquery-styler" rel="stylesheet">
  ...
</head>
```

But I get this failure:

```
expected xpath "//link" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Given all that, **how do I test a stylesheet**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check that a CSS file exists on a page, then you can do the following:

```
page.should have_xpath("//link[contains(@href, 'style.css')]")
```

That'll check whether there are any `<link>` elements where the `href` attribute contains `style.css`. The error about "expected xpath to return something" means that the XPath you provided didn't actually exist - why it thinks that, I'm not sure, as you have a perfectly valid `<link>` tag in the HTML you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

When I am checking for a css what I do is something like

`expect(page.body).to include('/home/ramon/source/unstilted/public/system_test/stylesheets/fancake/css/2.css')`