# RSpec: should have_selector failed, but title is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've google and read stackoverflow about 4 hours, but cannot understand, why test similar to rails tutorial fail.

Test is very simple:

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "Contacts page" do
    before { visit contacts_path }

    it { should have_selector(:title, text: "|") }
  end
end
```

So, I add save_and_open_page to see, what's wrong with my Contacts page, but it's looks good. Title tag is present and contain "|".

I cannot understand, what's wrong. I've:

- tryed get instead visit;
- response instead page;
- check something other permanently in body (body.should have_selector(:h1)).

Also I tryed to understand, how to improve rspec output to more infomative. At now I see:

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_selector(:title, text: "|") }
       expected id :title with text "|" to return something
```

Comment: Asked and answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129423/capybara-how-to-test-the-title-of-a-page

Comment: I'm not asked how. I asked why have_selector not work. And I found, that if I use string "title" instead symbol :title - my sample works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know `have_selector` is a Capybara matcher and according to the [tutorial](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) as a first argument you can use an html element name in quotes or a xpath notation, but not a symbol.

Comment: Thanks, I clear it to myself about 4 hours ago :) But, this is right answer and I mark it.