# How can I test page title with Capybara 2.0.2 and rspec 2.10.0?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I use Capybara 2.0.2 and Rspec 2.10.0 to test page title:

```
  page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Page title')
```

But it's doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: For anyone using Capybara 2.1.0+ you can use `expect(page).to have_title "my_title"` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14139814/805003

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and ended up writing my own matcher to make it work.
See StackOverflow Q&A [RSpec & Capybara 2.0 tripping up my have_selector tests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13573525/567863) for details and interesting discussion around the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of gems you are using but I ran into a similar instance where using `:text` failed but when I used `:content` it passed the test.

Try replacing

```
 page.should have_selector('title', :text => 'Page title')
```

with

```
page.should have_selector("title", :content => "Page title")
```

Comment: You shouldnt use :content as this key has been removed in later versions of Capybara. see this link for the reasons https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/602