# Hartl RoR Tutorial Chapter 5 Exercise 1: Failing test: it_should_behave_like and should_not have_title

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems with Hartl's RoR Tutorial Chapter 5 Exercise 1.

The exercise sets up the test spec. given in TEST SPEC below.

When I run "`bundle exec rspec spec/`", I get the error given in ERROR below.

If I comment out both:

```
it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
```

the test passes...

QUESTION: What's wrong with `it_should_behave_like` and `should_not have_title`

```
**ERROR**

o DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
F...F......

Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_title?' for #<Capybara::Session>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

**TEST SPEC**



require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  shared_examples_for "all static pages" do
    it { should have_content(heading) }
    it { should have_title(full_title(page_title)) }
  end

  describe "Home page" do
    before { visit root_path }
    let(:heading)    { 'Sample App' }
    let(:page_title) { '' }

    it_should_behave_like "all static pages"
    it { should_not have_title('| Home') }
  end

.......
.......
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Capybara to the version 2.1.0 in your Gemfile. `have_title` is one of the new selectors.

[Check out this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14139814/512507)